# angularjs and asp.net routing mix

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, routes

I'm using angularsj routing inside my asp.net mvc application.

Here's my configs for $routeProvider :

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
      .when('/Organization/Employee/:id', {
          controller: 'UserCtrl',
          templateUrl: '/Areas/Organization/App/user/partial/info.html'
      })
      .when('/Organization/Employee/:id/edit', {
          controller: 'EditCtrl',
          templateUrl: '/Areas/Organization/App/user/partial/edit.html'
      })
    .otherwise({        
        redirectTo: '/'
    })
    ;
}])
```

As you can see there only two routes I want to be handled by angularjs.
How I can make use asp.net for handling routing for the otherwise case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  .otherwise({
      controller: function ($location, $window) {
          $window.location.href = $location.path();
          return false;
      },
      template: ""
  });
```

That did the trick. But blink with an empty ng-view first. Maybe someone know's how to get rid of that blink?